# Creating labels for multiple levels

Tags: r, label, levels

So I have a data frame with multiple levels, shown below:

```
> levels
54 42 30 18 17 19  6  5 NA 78  4
```

I need to label these into 4 different groups

```
> labels
 "0-1" "1-2" "2-3" "3+"
```

I'm trying to use the following code, but I need the levels to be the same length as the labels. How do I do that?

```
df$y <- cut(df$x, levels, labels)
```

Comment: In the example levels provided, would all of the levels be labelled "3+"?

Comment: Use `cut` and specify the `labels` i.e. `cut(levels, breaks=4, labels=c("0-1", "1-2", "2-3", "3+"))`

Comment: The levels are in months, and the labels are in years.

Comment: @JohnnyP how in the world would anyone know that unless you said something? voting to close for being unclear

Comment: That worked perfectly when I switched the breaks to months instead of the years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `cut` can be useful

```
cut(levels%/%12+1, breaks=c(-Inf, 1, 2, 3,Inf), labels = c("0-1", "1-2", "2-3", "3+"))
#[1] 3+   3+   2-3  1-2  1-2  1-2  0-1  0-1  <NA> 3+   0-1 
#Levels: 0-1 1-2 2-3 3+
```

#### data

```
levels <- c(54, 42, 30, 18, 17, 19, 6, 5, NA, 78, 4)
```